# How to compare the elements of the list and find the total difference between each numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```
a=[123,456]
b=[789,345]
```

The operation that needs to be done is `(1-7)+(2-8)+(3-9)+(4-3)+(5-4)+(6-5)` and the total count should be returned.

Comment: Actually this question was asked to me today in an interview. I am a newbie to python. I couldn't figure out what to do. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`:

```
a=[123,456] 
b=[789,345]
a1 = ''.join(map(str, a))
b1 = ''.join(map(str, b))
final_sum = sum(c-d for c, d in zip(map(int, list(a1)), map(int, list(b1))))
```

Comment: No need to make `a1` and `b1` as `list`. +1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it now. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @SnehasishSaha glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[123,456] 
b=[789,345]
total = 0
for aa,bb in zip(a,b):
    for aaa,bbb in zip(str(aa), str(bb)):
        total += int(aaa) - int(bbb)
print (total)
```